# Cannot understand hash code equality from MSDN

Tags: c#, hash

Here's something I found from the MSDN, and I cannot understand this statement. I'd highly appreciate a code example that demonstrates this.

"Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes. "

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

Thank you everyone!

Comment: This is due to hash collisions. I'm not sure if there's a good way to demonstrate this in code though.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: "I don't understand" is a fact, not a question. Can you phrase your question in the form of a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd highly appreciate a code example that demonstrates this.

```
string s1 = "ꂢꂢ";
string s2 = "";
int h1 = s1.GetHashCode();
int h2 = s2.GetHashCode();
bool b1 = s1 == s2;
bool b2 = h1 == h2;
```

b1 is false. b2 is true.

There are only four billion hash codes, but there are infinitely many strings. Therefore at least two of them must have the same hash code. I've provided two of them; try to find more.

For more information, see:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/12/what-curious-property-does-this-string-have.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/15/the-curious-property-revealed.aspx

Comment: how do I copy `"ꂢꂢ"` to Visual studio, when I try copying and pasting this code in VS, it changes `"ꂢꂢ"` to something like `S`, but not real `S`, I can't past that here from VS.

Answer (score 7):

This can be explained through application of the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). The `GetHashCode()` method returns an `int`, which can represent (up to) about 4 billion values. It is possible for there to be more than 4 billion unequal objects existing at one time in a single program (assume a 64-bit platform!). Therefore, two or more of those objects must return the same value from `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: Or `dirichlet drawer principle`

Comment: "It is possible for there to be more than 4 billion objects existing at one time" - it's not the number of objects (concurrently or otherwise), but the number of *distinct values* they can take on that's relevant to hashing (obligatory mention of edge case: objects for which the address is considered [part of] the value).  E.g. considering that a 32-bit hash of a 64-bit number needs to map 4 billion **squared** values that the later might take onto the 4 billion hash outputs possible, there's clearly going to be an average of 4 billion inputs hashing to each output.

Answer (score 0):

Two people who were born in the same day were born in the same month. However, the reverse is not true: two people who were born in the same month do not imply, that they were born in the same day, because different people can have birthdays in a different days.